# Workflow email notification link not working

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I have been working on an 'issue list' in which one user 'add an item' and assign responsibility to another user. I created a workflow in SPD 2013 and assign "Encoded Absolute URL" for an item. The purpose was the responsible user gets an email with the link to an issue and when he/she clicks on the link it will take the user to the SharePoint issue item. 

 The user is getting email but the link in an email is not working. When user click on the link, a file of size 0 KB is downloaded rather to take the user on the list item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this instead:

`Workflow Context -> Current Item URL`

You can even use this in a hyperlink, using this as the address and the Title as the displayname of the hyperlink

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. The solution is working almost perfectly whereas, the link which is generated in an email is not an hyperlink i.e. i have to copy and paste in the browser to open it. I cannot simply click on it and it takes me to browser. Is there any way to make it click able link??

Comment: Use it in a hyperlink within the body of the email. The hyperlink should give you two fields, an address and a display text. Or you should be able to use it as `<a href='[WorkflowContext%CurrentItemURL]'>My TItle here</a>` since the email bodies can render html

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply really appreciated. Once we realised that there is an hyperlink button "Define email message area" and that work straight away.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the link with the current item id.

/Lists/ListName/DispForm.aspx?ID=[%Current Item:ID%] 
/Lists/ListName/EditForm.aspx?ID=[%Current Item:ID%]

I use this often because I use different view's or if I want launch them right into edit mode

Answer (score -1):

You may try this. Rather then using the absolute URL option, try using Add or Change lookup tab. The look should be like this : 
Data source: (Select your list here)
Field from Source : (Select Title here)

Please let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks Mohd for putting effort to help me. I believe that this will not work. The aim is to send a link via email so the user can click on it and navigate to the list item. If i just add a title it will just sending me the name only.